# MongoDB findOne() returning empty subdocuments array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using Mongoose and MongoDB v. 6.4.1. I have defined a document collection with embedded subdocuments using the following Mongoose schemas:

```
import mongoose, { Collection } from 'mongoose';
const connectStr = 'mongodb://localhost/appdb';
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

//Open connection to database
mongoose.connect(connectStr, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
  .then(
    () =>  {console.log(`Connected to ${connectStr}.`)},
    err => {console.error(`Error connecting to ${connectStr}: ${err}`)}
  );

//Define schema that maps to a document in the Users collection in the appdb
//database.
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const roundSchema = new Schema({
  date: {type: Date, required: true},
  course: {type: String, required: true},
  type: {type: String, required: true, enum: ['practice','tournament']},
  holes: {type: Number, required: true, min: 1, max: 18},
  strokes: {type: Number, required: true, min: 1, max: 300},
  minutes: {type: Number, required: true, min: 1, max: 240},
  seconds: {type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 60},
  SGS: {type: Number, 
        default: function(){return (this.strokes * 60) + (this.minutes * 60) + this.seconds}
       },
  notes: {type: String, required: true}
});

const userSchema = new Schema({
  id: {type: String, required: true}, //unique identifier for user
  password: String, //unencrypted password (for now!)
  displayName: {type: String, required: true}, //Name to be displayed within app
  authStrategy: {type: String, required: true}, //strategy used to authenticate, e.g., github, local
  profileImageUrl: {type: String, required: true}, //link to profile image
  rounds: [roundSchema],
  securityQuestion: {type: String},
  securityAnswer: {type: String, required: function() {return this.securityQuestion ? true: false}}
});

//Convert schema to model
const User = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
```

In an Express.js GET route, I am using the following code to query for a specific document:

```
try {
    let thisUser = await User.findOne({id: req.params.userId});
    console.log("thisUser: " + JSON.stringify(thisUser));
    if (!thisUser) {
      return res.status(400).send("No user account with specified userId was found in database.");
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json(thisUser.rounds);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).message("Unexpected error occurred when looking up user in database: " + err);
  }
```

My console.log statement confirms that the above route in fact obtains the desired document, e.g.:

```
thisUser: {"_id":"5e6704234f3864318caedd12","id":"chundhau@gmail.com","password":"GoCougs20","displayName":"chundhau@gmail.com","authStrategy":"local","profileImageUrl":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4b565c54d37b3f5ad4caa1c129e865b8","securityQuestion":"First pet?","securityAnswer":"Daisy","__v":0,"rounds":[]}
```

When I look at this same document in MongoDB Compass Community, I can confirm that its `rounds` subdocument array has several elements:

[image: MongoDB Compass Community Screeenshot]

However, as shown in the `console.log` output above, **`rounds` is coming back as an empty array**. I have confirmed that (a) `rounds` is in fact an array (using `Array.isArray()`) and that (b) `rounds` has no elements (`thisUser.rounds.length === 0`).

Shouldn't I be able to access all of the subdocuments through `thisUser.rounds`? What have I done wrong?

Comment: What version of Mongo are you using?
Does the following help? https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6141
Could you also show `roundSchema` and the order of instructions registering the models?

Comment: I have updated the question to include version number (6.4.1), `roundSchema` and order of instructions. I could not see much relevance in the post you referred me to. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered a solution. I changed:

```
let thisUser = await User.findOne({id: req.params.userId});
```

to

```
let thisUser = await User.findOne({id: req.params.userId}).lean();
```

Miraculously, `thisuser.rounds` was no longer empty. It instead contained all of the array elements I could see when I inspected the document in MongoDB Compass Community!

While this solution worked, I do not know *why* it worked. If anyone could help me understand what's going on here, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: The lean option tells Mongoose to skip hydrating the result documents. This makes queries faster and less memory intensive, but the result documents are plain old JavaScript objects (POJOs), not Mongoose documents.  [more](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

Comment: @ManjeetThakur Thanks! Why did this allow me to access the document's subdocuments? When I didn't use the `lean()` option, the subdocuments came back as an empty array in the query. Can you explain this?